# How can i authenticate an eureka client service before registering to a eureka server?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt, netflix-eureka

I am new to eureka but i  know eureka provide basic authentication with username & password. However, thats not i need. The scenario would be before the service registers himself with the discovery, it needs to be validated by some token specific for that service and upon validation it register itself with the discovery server. It would be great, if i could get some examples as a pointer.